# How can I redirect just a single blogger.com page to an external URL with Target Blank

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code in my blog, but this script opens the external URL in the native tab itself. I want to redirect it to a new tab altogether.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://externalblog.blogger.com/externalpost";
</script>
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/1611516

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open("http://externalblog.blogger.com/externalpost")`; This should work.

Comment: I tried this but does not work. I use blogger and in one of my posts in the home page I want to direct users to an external link in a new tab. Thank you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I disagree. The user did attempt to answer the question. Whether the answer is correct or not is another story, but incorrect answers are not off topic.

Comment: @Mike, well, in order to make it more an answer than a comment the user should add some explanation why his proposal should work. Otherwise it sounds like a blind guess, which is rather a comment

Comment: @YanSklyarenko You've got a point. I generally find code-only answers pretty useless, however considering the question is only one line too and the difference is one word, I wouldn't think it would require much explanation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.open` method to open in a new window / tab

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) for details.

Here is an example

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

function openRequestedPopup() {
  windowObjectReference = window.open("http://externalblog.blogger.com/externalpost", "Blogger Window", strWindowFeatures);
}
```

Call the `openRequestedPopup()` method on whatever condition you want it to open. Alternately, if you already have the link while rendering the  HTML, use the target="_blank" attribute in the anchor tag.

Comment: May you kindly explain with practical examples of all elements in the script with the external link I have provided in my query. Thank you.

Comment: Added the example. Please state your problem clearly, and advise you to do some preliminary research before posting the question on Stack Overflow.